# Use debugger in Visual Studio Code with Docker

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I am working on a project where we use Docker to develop an application. Currently I'm running my programmes by typing `docker-compose run --rm app` in the console.

Then I can run my scrip like this `root@ce4d1325fb94:/home/app# python3 example.py`. But I would like to use my debugger. Normally I can use it be pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

I have found *[Debug containerized apps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common)* and *[Debug Python within a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python)*.

But id does not work.

I get the error `Could not find the task 'docker-run: debug'` or `ConfigError: The project 'Projekte_635c102' is not a valid java project.`

What am I doing wrong? Note: I have no clue what Docker exactly is. I was told to use it.

I've done everything exactly as @MingJie-MSFT said. I’m still getting the same `Could not find the task 'docker-run: debug'` error. I can't create an example since I have no clue what I'm doing. I never worked  with Docker or got an explanation on how to use it. I was just told to use the existing code. I can give you the Dockerfile if that is of any help:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /home/app
# Pass 8 and 63 to tzdata to set up the default time zone
RUN apt-get update && echo 8 63 | apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip libgdal-dev gdal-bin default-jre && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I also tried to just type `docker-run: debug` in my console while being in the container.

```
root@cd70584fb560:/home/app# docker-run debug
```

and I've got

```
bash: docker-run: command not found
```

I've tried to include a `"tasks"` in my *launch.json* file. But again no luck. I thought maybe it's trying to find the `"preLaunchTask"` specified in the *launch.json* file before. Again I am absolutely clueless here. How is this *launch.json* file supposed to work? What are those commands supposed to do? I only know a bit of Python and barely anything about using command-line commands.

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
      "type": "docker",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
      "python": {
        "pathMappings": [
          {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/app"
          }
        ],
        "projectType": "django"
      }
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "docker-run",
      "label": "docker-run: debug",
      "dependsOn": ["docker-build"],
      "python": {
        "args": ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--nothreading", "--noreload"],
        "file": "manage.py" // how to I change this to current file?
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: please be more clear about what question you are asking.

Comment: Can you use Python directly on your host system instead?  MacOS and Linux systems generally have it preinstalled.  Most development tasks are easier without involving a container, especially if you're unsure why Docker is in your stack.

Comment: @DavidMaze sadly not. I've tried that. As far as I understand our docker provides java (?) or makes it work. I'm just a physics student working on a project that someone else started.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common#_python) about debug in Docker.

> ConfigError: The project 'Projekte_635c102' is not a valid java project.

It identifies your project as a Java project. It seems that your *launch.json* file has an error. Check your *launch.json* file. It should look like this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
      "type": "docker",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
      "python": {
        "pathMappings": [
          {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/app"
          }
        ],
        "projectType": "django"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I copied the json from the docs. Now I get the ```Could not find the task 'docker-run: debug'``` error again.

Comment: @AkutLuna I added my answer. Is this feasible? If not, please improve the question and provide an example for reproduction

Comment: I added all the stuff I tried. It still didn't work.